# The correct place of the adverb "nearly"

Tags: grammar

As far as I know, the adverb "nearly" can be used in an initial or medial position. However, I have seen it in a final position in an exercise book for non-native students:

He studied 3 hours a day "nearly".

My question is: can we put " nearly" at  the end of the sentence?

Comment: So, everything you've learned so far suggests that you can't:  what makes you ask whether you can?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, not everything they encountered suggests one can't. The exercise book suggests one can.

Comment: Pedants would probably insist that if you put *nearly* at the end of a statement, it should be preceded by a comma (and in principle it should apply to the *whole* of that statement). But consider *He nearly drank 8 pints* (but actually he might not have drunk *any*) vs *He drank nearly 8 pints* (he definitely drank several pints, probably 7 plus a large fraction of a pint). But *He drank 8 pints, nearly* would usually be understood to imply the second sense there.

Comment: The position of *nearly* can vary greatly. It doesn't always work in initial position (consider "Nearly he punched Mary," which sounds wrong). And it doesn't always work at the end, although it can ("I ran a mile, nearly.") Placing the adverb at the end is kind of infelicitous since the first part of the sentence indicates that one ran a *full* mile (or studied a *full* three hours). This indication is cancelled when one encounters the adverb.

Comment: The position of a hedge like _nearly_ does not have to do with its position in the sentence (beginning, end). It has to do with the words being hedged. Those words always occur after _nearly_, so it can't occur as the last word in a sentence. And it can only occur as the first word if it's immediately followed by its focus constituent; i.e, _Nearly everybody came to the party_, but not *_Nearly Bill and Sue came to the party._

Comment: First of all, I am not a native speaker. And I have learned English through formal textbooks. I asked because in informal English, rules can be ignored.

Comment: I do agree with all your comments. I think the only use at end position should be preceded with a comma as FumbleFingers said.

Comment: Technically you can put it anywhere in the sentence, even at the very beginning. But being able to put it anywhere doesn't mean it'll make sense when it's put anywhere. The point of language is to reach the widest possible audience so that you're understood. So nearly always, one should put 'nearly' before the adverb or noun or phrase it modifies.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it's an interesting question. I'm sure it can be done, but I'd expect to see it more in dialogue or spoken language then in, say, an essay or a textbook.

> "The walk was so long and hard, it killed us, nearly."
>
> "That clock is an hour slow, well, nearly."

However, the above sentences may not be considered syntactically correct. Seeing that nearly is an adverb, it usually needs to precede whatever it is describing. List of [adverbs](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/wordlist/adverbs.shtml)

> That boat nearly toppled over.
>
> The child was out side until nearly two'o'clock.

[This](http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/nearly/1.html) website has a ton of example sentences. To answer your question, it can be done. However, I don't think it should be made a practice.

Comment: That's different. You're referring to the use of "nearly" in clause structure, where its linear position is 'fairly' flexible. What we're actually talking about here is "nearly" as a modifier in NP structure and what happens when it's extracted and placed outside the NP.

Answer (score 0):

The terms 'initial' and 'medial' usually refer to the linear position of an AdvP in clause structure where it would be modifying a verb or VP, as in "We nearly got killed!"; "We got killed nearly!"

Here, you're considering "nearly" as a possible modifier of the NP "3 hours a day", so different considerations apply. Its default position as a modifier in phrase structure would be at the front of the NP, i.e. "*nearly 3 hours a day*". If you extract it and put it outside the NP it would be said to be **prosodically detached**, i.e. set off from the phrase and indeed the rest of the clause by an intonational phrase boundary, and normally by a comma in writing.  In this case it would have the status of a supplement, an element that is not integrated into the structure of the phrase that it would normally be part of.

Supplements are not modifiers; rather, they have 'anchors'; in this case the anchor would be the NP "3 hours a day". So, yes, you can put it at the end of the sentence as in your eaxample, but be sure to take account of the different syntax.